# Get value of array with different variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

I have to create three different variable arrays:
The first array is multidimensional and the other two are one-dimensional.
I have to get the lowest value of multidimensional array and the name of the person who has earned that value.

What you do not know is how to associate two arrays of different variables.

[image]

```
    $notas=array(array(5, 7.5, 6), 
             array(9, 6.5, 8), 
             array(8, 5.5, 7.5), 
             array(6.5, 5, 4));

$asignaturas=array("so", "hw", "html");
$nombres=array("Pepe", "Juan", "Ana", "Miren");



echo "<h4>The lowest note in all asginaturas and the name of the student who has earned </h4>";

for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $array[$i]=min($notas[$i]);
}
$menor= min($array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3]);
echo $menor;
```

So far I've only received the smallest value of multidimensional array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u give an example of the expected output?

Comment: yes...The lowest note is 4 and was achieved by Miren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$notas=array(array(5, 7.5, 6), 
             array(9, 6.5, 8), 
             array(8, 5.5, 7.5), 
             array(6.5, 5, 4));

$asignaturas=array("so", "hw", "html");
$nombres=array("Pepe", "Juan", "Ana", "Miren");



echo "<h4>The lowest note in all asginaturas and the name of the student who has earned </h4>";

for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $array[$i]=min($notas[$i]);
}
$menor= min($array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3]);
$names=array();                    // in case  multi  winners
for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
   if( $menor==$array[$i])
   {
     $names[]= $nombres[i];
   }
}
foreach($names as $winner)
{
   echo $winner."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have obtained the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bild one multidimensional array:

```
$notas = array('Pepe' => array("so" => 5, "hw" => 7.5, "html" => 6), 
    'Juan' => array("so" => 9, "hw" => 6.5, "html" => 8), 
    'Ana' => array("so" => 8, "hw" => 5.5, "html" => 7.5), 
    'Miren' => array("so" => 6.5, "hw" => 5, "html" => 4));

$low_name = '';
$low_st = '';
$low_point = 0;
foreach ($notas as $name => $points) {
    if ('' == $low_name)
        $low_name = $name;
    foreach ($points as $k => $value) {
        if ('' == $low_st)
            $low_st = $k;
        if (0 == $low_point)
            $low_point = $value;

        if ($value < $low_point) {
            $low_point = $value;
            $low_st = $k;
            $low_name = $name;
        }
    }
}
echo $low_name . ' got ' . $low_point . ' in ' . $low_st;
// result is "Miren got 4 in html"
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about doing so but my teacher wants the arrays are on different variables and that's what I do not know how to do.